# "Could not resolve com.aerospike:spring-data-aerospike:1.0.0.RELEASE" error in gradle

Tags: spring-data

I'm trying to add spring-data-aerospike dependency to gradle build file.

Below is my build.gradle file.

```
group 'spring-data-as-demo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   mavenLocal()
   }

dependencies {
   compile group: 'com.aerospike', name: 'spring-data-aerospike', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
 }
```

The error is -

```
$ gradle clean compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.aerospike:spring-data-aerospike:1.0.0.RELEASE.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve com.aerospike:spring-data-aerospike:1.0.0.RELEASE.
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-data-aerospike-1.0.0.RELEASE.pom
     > Could not find org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
       Searched in the following locations:
           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-parent-1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-parent-1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
           file:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
           file:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-parent-1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom .
  file:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-data-parent-1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

But when I created the project as maven and below is pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>spring-data-as-mvn-demo</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-as-mvn-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I compiled the project using `mvn clean compile`, it is successful.

Do I need to add different repository to resolve the dependency?

Also, I tried to tag [spring-data-Aerospike], but the tag is not recognized somehow.